# MVC View Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda, visual-studio-2015

how can i get the value of val to use it in the Lambda Expression here
is that the right way or there is another way to get it ??

```
{enter code here

        function CallChangefunc(val) {
            @ActiveSwimmerID = val;
            @ActiveSwimmer = @Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SwimmerID == val);

        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Razor syntax to write javascript code. Think about how a request is handled by MVC:

- Client sends a request to the server
- Server processes the request and renders the page using razor
- The rendered page is send as *HTML* to the client; it does not contain any razor syntax anymore!
- Page is rendered at the client computer; this is where the javascript code runs

You can however use Razor to generate JS objects, and then write JS code to process them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var allSwimmers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllSwimmers)); // array of JS objects
var currentSwimmer = undefined;
$.each(allSwimmers, function(index, swimmer){ if (swimmer.Id == currentSwimmerId) { currentSwimmer = swimmer; return true; } });
```

Comment: Thanks alot...i had left this project along time ago but i think your answer will help